# what is f:optionalBlock in jelly

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jelly

I have seen a jelly file with f:optional block

```
<?jelly escape-by-default='true'?>
<j:jelly xmlns:j="jelly:core" xmlns:f="/lib/form" xmlns:st="jelly:stapler">
    <j:choose>
        <j:when test="${instance == null}">
            <f:entry title="${%File}" field="file">
                <input type="file" name="file" size="40" jsonAware="yes"/>
            </f:entry>
        </j:when>
        <j:otherwise>
            <f:invisibleEntry>
                <f:textbox field="fileName"/>
            </f:invisibleEntry>
            <f:invisibleEntry>
                <f:textbox field="secretBytes"/>
            </f:invisibleEntry>
            <f:optionalBlock title="${%upload(instance.fileName)}" inline="true">
                <f:entry title="${%File}" field="file">
                    <input type="file" name="file" size="40" jsonAware="yes"/>
                </f:entry>
            </f:optionalBlock>
        </j:otherwise>
    </j:choose>
    <st:include page="id-and-description" class="${descriptor.clazz}"/>
</j:jelly>
```

What is f:optional block doing here, i mean whats its significance here ?

Answer (score 0):

Jelly code internally converts to simple HTML and JavaScript code.
`<f:optionalBlock>` block is used to display a checkbox. When you click on this checkbox, the fields inside the checkbox are displayed on the UI.
In your example, file parameter will be displayed on UI.
We can use `inline` and `checked` properties of `<f:optional>` block